# Active side menu on "INSPINIA" admin theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, inspinia

I want to highlight the active page on the side bar menu using JavaScript. I am using [INSPINIA](https://github.com/Chuibility/inspinia) theme.

I've tried using JavaScript and it's working fine for normal menus. But it's not working for submenus. I want to display `in` class instead of `active` class for submenus. Please check my code and help me.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
   <div class="sidebar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu">
         <li>
            <a href="dashboard.html"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i><span class="nav-label">Dashboards</span></a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-building"></i><span class="nav-label">Company</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
               <li><a href="addcompany.html">Add Company</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">View Company</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="mailbox.html"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span class="nav-label">Person</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
               <li><a href="addperson.html">Add Person</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">View Person</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location;
    // for sidebar menu but not for metismenu submenu
    $('ul.metismenu a').filter(function () {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parent().siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
    // for metismenu which is like a submenu
    $('ul.nav-second-level a').filter(function () {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parentsUntil(".metismenu > .nav-second-level").siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
});
```

Expected output

```
<li class="active">
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-building"></i><span class="nav-label">Company</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
   <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse in">
      <li><a href="addcompany.html">Add Company</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">View Company</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Actual Output

```
<li class="active">
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-building"></i><span class="nav-label">Company</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
   <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse active">
      <li><a href="addcompany.html">Add Company</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">View Company</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
$(function() {
    setNavigation();
});

function setNavigation() {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path[0] == '/' ? path.substr(1) : path; //it will remove the dash in the URL

    $("ul.metismenu a").each(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        }
    });

    $("ul.metismenu .nav-second-level a").each(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
            $(this).parent().parent().closest('li').addClass('active');
            $(this).closest('ul').addClass('in');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not work. Instead, use this one:

```
$(function(){
    var current = location.pathname;

    $('ul.metismenu li a').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        }
    });

    $('ul.metismenu .nav-second-level a').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('href').indexOf(current));
        if($(this).attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1)  {
            $(this).parent().parent().closest('li').addClass('active');
            $(this).closest('ul').addClass('in');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

acmsohail's answer helped me but I found a problem that if there are two urls that start the same way, the one with the largest extension will show two selected ones.
Then I leave the code that takes the correct element.

```
 function setNavigation() {
    var path = location.href;
    var lstElem = [];
    var classIndex;
    path = path[0] == '/' ? path.substr(1) : path;

    $("ul.metismenu a").each(function (i,e) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (path.substring(0, href.length)  === href) {

            lstElem.push({
                element : e,
                count : href.length
            })

        }
    });

    if(lstElem.length > 0)
    {
        //i get the element with max length
        classIndex = $(lstElem.reduce(function(prev, current) {
            return (prev.count > current.count) ? prev : current
        })["element"]);

        classIndex.closest('li').addClass('active');

        lstElem = [];            
    }

    $("ul.metismenu .nav-second-level a").each(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
            lstElem.push({
                element : e,
                count : href.length
            })
        }
    });

    if(lstElem.length > 0)
    {
        classIndex = $(lstElem.reduce(function(prev, current) {
            return (prev.count > current.count) ? prev : current
        })["element"]);

        classIndex.parent().parent().closest('li').addClass('active');
        classIndex.closest('ul').addClass('in');
    }
}
```